# Link shared library when using WAF and NS3

Tags: ubuntu, waf, ns-3

This is a query related to the network simulator called NS3.

Say that I want to build a program called 'MyProgram' and to link a shared library when building it.
How do I do this with WAF? I have put 'MyProgram' in a directory called 'examples/thesis' and created a wscript. I am also putting the files needed for 'MyProgram' in the scratch-directory. [Some more info about the usage of WAF when building files in NS3: [Link](http://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.6/tutorial/tutorial_22.html) ]

This is the command that I would run to build 'MyProgram' without the library: ./waf --build MyProgram

How do I link the library the shared library when building 'MyProgram'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lib` named argument to pass a list of libraries into program.

```or-tag-here
def build(ctx):
    ctx(rule='cp ${SRC} ${TGT}', source='src/main.c', target='main.c')
    ctx.program(source='main.c', target='app', lib=['mysqlclient'])
```